# Is this a bug in the solution manual of Measures, Integrals and Martingales by Rene Schilling?

Tags: measure-theory

I am reading the solution of problem 4.3 of [Measures, Integrals and Martingales by Rene Schilling](http://www.motapa.de/measures_integrals_and_martingales/).

> **Problem 4.3.**
>   *Show that the function $\gamma : \mathcal{B}(\Bbb{R}) \rightarrow  \{0,1\}$
>   \begin{align*}
> \gamma (A):=\begin{cases}0 &\text{if $A$ is countable}\\ 1 &\text{if $A^c$ is countable}\\ \end{cases} 
> \end{align*}
>    is not a measure on the measurable space $(\Bbb{R},\mathcal{B}(\Bbb{R}))$*
>
> **Proof.**
>   Take the sets $A=(1,\infty )$ and $B=(-\infty ,-1)$ which are disjoint, not countable and both have non-countable complements. Hence 
>   $$
> \gamma (A)=\gamma (B)=1.
> $$
>
> ...

The proof goes on, but my point is that there is an error here. It seems to me that both $\gamma(1,\infty )$ and $\gamma(-\infty ,-1)$ or simply not defined.

Comment: Perhaps $\gamma^\ast(A) = \gamma^\ast(B) = 1$ with the outer measure was meant? In any case, yes, $\gamma(A)$ and $\gamma(B)$ are not defined.

Comment: @Kasper If you don't mind, I'll point the author to the mistake (since I know him quite well).

Comment: @saz Sure. Is this solution manual also written by Rene Schilling ?

Comment: @Kasper At least parts of it. Some of the solutions were written by staff members.

Comment: @saz This is maybe a crazy idea, but I always wonder, why not setting a free resource like this on github, and make it open source ? I've spotted like 10 very small errors, or misspelling etc, but I don't feel it's worth bothering Rene Schilling, with stuff like, on page 13, line 10, somewhere in the middle you probably meant '+' instead of minus. But if the TeX files of this where on github, I could just do pull request, the author can check if he agrees, and the solution will be fixed in a minute.

Comment: @Kasper I can't speak for him, but I would say that one reason is that he wants to avoid that someone can copy the TeX-code from there (e.g. doing homework by copy+paste). If you don't want to bother him, then I can give you my e-mail address and I'll correct them.

Comment: @saz Okay, there is some point in that. On the other hand, you could say, that it is easy to spot those copy-paste students, as their homework look exactly the same as the official solution manual. Sounds good, you can find my email adress at my profile.

Comment: @saz I emailed you

Comment: @Kasper Thanks, got it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @DanielFischer pointed out, the solution is indeed not correct. If you want to make sense of this exercise (and the given solution), then modify it as follows:

> Show that the function $\gamma : \mathcal{B}(\Bbb{R}) \rightarrow  \{0,1\}$
>   \begin{align*}
> \gamma (A):=\begin{cases}0 &\text{if $A$ is countable}\\ 1 &\text{otherwise}\\ \end{cases}
> \end{align*}
>    is not a measure on the measurable space $(\Bbb{R},\mathcal{B}(\Bbb{R}))$.

Basically, the author wants to emphasize that it highly depends on the measurable space whether a given mapping is a measure or not. The following exercise is very similar in spirit:

> Let $\Omega = \mathbb{N}$ and $\mathcal{A} := \{A \subseteq \mathbb{N}; A \, \text{or} \, A^c$ is finite$\}.$ Then $$\mu(A) := \begin{cases} 0 & A \, \text{finite} \\ 1 & A^c \, \text{finite} \end{cases}$$ does not define a measure on $(\Omega,\mathcal{A})$.